# Problems with Jpa Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

There are a lot of errors when I try to run it, I cant understand
exactly what happened.
here it is some of them:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.findAll(Unknown Source)
```

I did it by one guide, but this guide is quite old, maybe I should change the JPA dependencies, or create my database differently?
here it is the repository of the second lesson about JPA
https://github.com/drucoder/sweater/tree/JPA_Postgres

This is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=1506
spring.jpa.generate-ddl-auto=update
```

I create my empty database sweater by pgadmin.
Also, my ide shows me that there is Typo in word Postgresql.
This is my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @Autowired
    private MessageRepo messageRepo;
    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(
            @RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name,
            Map<String, Object> model
    ) {
        model.put("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String main(Map<String, Object> model) {
       Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();
        model.put("messages", messages);
        return "main";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String add(@RequestParam String text, @RequestParam String tag, Map<String, Object> model){
       Message message = new Message(text,tag);
       messageRepo.save(message);
        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();
        model.put("messages", messages);
        return "main";
    }


    @PostMapping("filter")
    public String filter(@RequestParam String filter, Map<String, Object> model) {
        Iterable<Message> messages;

        if (filter != null && !filter.isEmpty()) {
            messages = messageRepo.findByTag(filter);
        } else {
            messages = messageRepo.findAll();
        }

        model.put("messages", messages);

        return "main";
    }
}
```

Comment: "*i will upload photos, because there is a lot of code line*" Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I guess you also have the connection string in your `application.properties` ? (`spring.datasource.url=...`)

Answer (score 1):

Change your application.properties from

```
 spring.datasource.username=postgres
 spring.datasource.password=1506
 spring.jpa.generate-ddl-auto=update
```

to

```
 spring.datasource.username=postgres
 spring.datasource.password=1506
 spring.jpa.generate-ddl-auto=update     
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/{your db name}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is still a lot of errors, but thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @EmmAngellow Are the errors the same as you posted or are you getting different errors now ?

Comment: Yes, now the errors are different and has to do with sql and jpa, as i understand, thank you